# Change label text from completion handler

Tags: swift

I have a sample view with a button and a label.
When user press the button an action receives a json from an external site and I need to put a string at the label.

I'm trying to do this from the completion handler but the label outlet is not recognized at this point.

Here is my code :

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, NSURLSessionDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var lblReceivedText: UILabel!

    var session : NSURLSession!


    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder)
    {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)

        let configuration = NSURLSessionConfiguration.defaultSessionConfiguration()
        configuration.timeoutIntervalForRequest = 15.0

        session = NSURLSession(configuration : configuration, delegate : self, delegateQueue : nil )

    }


    override func viewDidLoad()
    {
        super.viewDidLoad()

    }


    @IBAction func btnGerarMensagem(sender: AnyObject)

    {

        var errorx : NSError?
        let url = NSURL( string: "http://labs.bible.org/api/?passage=random&type=json")

        let task = session.dataTaskWithURL(url! ,
            completionHandler: { [weak self] (data: NSData!,
                response : NSURLResponse! ,
                error : NSError! ) in

                var error: NSError?
                var array = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: nil, error: &error) as NSArray
                var citacao: NSDictionary = array.objectAtIndex(0) as NSDictionary

                var Quote = citacao["text"] as String
                lblReceivedText.text = Quote                
                self!.session.finishTasksAndInvalidate()


        })

        task.resume()

    } // IBAction




}
```

Answer (score 1):

The compiler should be giving you a warning that you need to use `self` when referencing your `UILabel` property. Try this instead:

```
let task = session.dataTaskWithURL(url! ,
    completionHandler: { [weak self] (data: NSData!,
        response : NSURLResponse! ,
        error : NSError! ) in

        var error: NSError?
        var array = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: nil, error: &error) as NSArray
        var citacao: NSDictionary = array.objectAtIndex(0) as NSDictionary

        var Quote = citacao["text"] as String
        NSOperationQueue.mainQueue().addOperationWithBlock {
            self?.lblReceivedText.text = Quote
        }
})
```

*Note:* if you're declaring `[weak self]` in a closure, unwrap with `self?` instead of `self!`. At that point they have the same effect, but the second will crash your app if the handler comes back after your view controller has been deallocated.

Comment: Hi Nate, now at the first run the println shows the result ok at the the console ( Citacao 0 {
    bookname = Jeremiah;
    chapter = 18;
    text = "Then the Lord said to me,";
    verse = 5;
}
 ) but nothing at the UI label. For subsequent processings -> 2015-02-17 18:25:28.919 Biblia[9568:323097] Attempted to create a task in a session that has been invalidated
2015-02-17 18:25:32.559 Biblia[9568:323097] Attempted to create a task in a session that has been invalidated

Comment: After remove  self?.session.finishTasksAndInvalidate(), I have no more errors but the label remains blank...

Comment: Sorry, didn't look past the first issue. You need to get back on the main thread to update the label, since it's part of the UI. And, yes, you don't need to invalidate the session there, particularly if you're going to reuse it. See updated answer.

Comment: Thank you ! Running ok after add this code to the closure :               var backgroundQueue = NSOperationQueue()
                       backgroundQueue.addOperationWithBlock(){
                               NSOperationQueue.mainQueue().addOperationWithBlock()
                                {
                                       self!.lblReceivedText.text = Quote
                                   }
                           }